# Import multi-sized product with single SKU

Tags: drupal, drupal-commerce, csv-import, drupal-feeds

I have regular Drupal Commerce setup with installed Feeds, Feeds Tamper and Commerce Feeds modules.
Here is tiny piece of the CSV file I'm trying to import:

```
SKU,Title,Price,Sizes,Model
JKR122/1,Red T-Shirt,44,"42,44,46",JKR122
JKR122/2,Blue T-Shirt,44,"42,44,46",JKR122
```

Is it possible using Feeds Tamper, to explode "Sizes" column and import each as separate product. Probably it will be needed to append exploded size to SKU.

I'm no pro in Excel, so if it is possible to easily reformat this huge CSV file, please tell me how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As problem had to be solved today, I wrote PHP-script which reformats my CSV:

I'll leave question opened, in case anuone knows if this can be done by "Drupal-way".

```
<?php

define('ATTR_SIZE', 'Sizes');
define('ATTR_SKU', 'SKU');
define('IMPORT_FILE', 'import_file.csv');
define('EXPORT_FILE', 'export_file.csv');
define('CSV_DELIMITER', ',');

// Open csv
if(!file_exists(IMPORT_FILE) || !is_readable(IMPORT_FILE))
  die('Check file');

$header = NULL;
$all_rows = array();

if (($handle = fopen(IMPORT_FILE, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
  while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, CSV_DELIMITER)) !== FALSE) {
    if (!$header)
      $header = $row;
    else
      $all_rows[] = array_combine($header, $row);
  }
  fclose($handle);
}

// Process csv
$new_rows = array();

foreach ($all_rows as $key => $row) {
  if (!empty($row[ATTR_SIZE])) {
    $original_row = $row;
    $sizes = explode(',', $row[ATTR_SIZE]);

    foreach ($sizes as $size) {
      $trimmed_size = trim($size);

      if (!empty($trimmed_size)) {
        $row = $original_row;
        $row[ATTR_SIZE] = $trimmed_size; // Save size
        $row[ATTR_SKU] = $row[ATTR_SKU] . '/' . $trimmed_size; // Modify SKU
        $new_rows[] = $row; // Add new row
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    $new_rows[] = $row;
  }
}

// Save csv
$header = NULL;
$handle = fopen(EXPORT_FILE, 'w');

foreach ($new_rows as $fields) {
  if (!$header) {
    fputcsv($handle, array_keys($fields));
    $header = TRUE;
  }
  fputcsv($handle, $fields);
}
fclose($handle);
```